# Smalltalk - Methods with Multiple Parameters

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm struggling to figure out how to define methods that take in multiple arguments/parameters and how to call those methods.

For example, say I had a method `doSomething` that formed part of a class with an instance called `myInstance`.

In Java:

The declaration within the class: `void doSomething(int param1, int param2) {...};`

Calling the method: `myInstance.doSomething(1, 10);`

How would I declare, and then use, something similar in Smalltalk?

Comment: You can get most of the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205533/gnu-smalltalk-inheritance-and-multiple-parameter-methods-constructors

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski Thanks, I've managed to figure it out. Definitely an interesting syntax to wrap my head around!